# Stacks using push and pop

Tags: java, stack

Currently I am writing a method that receives a stack and must go through that stack and add all of the even numbers to a new stack and then return the new stack. For example, if the stack contains 1,3,4,5,7,8,10...the new stack would contain only 4,8,10 after adding it. So far this is my code but can't seem to get them to pass.

```
public class StackExample {
public static Stack<Integer> getEvenNumbers(Stack<Integer> stack) {
Stack<Integer> a = stack;
Stack<Integer> c = new Stack<Integer>();
System.out.println(length(stack));
if(length(stack)==1)
{
    return stack;
}
while (!(a.isEmpty())) {
    int num = a.pop();
    if (num % 2 == 0) {
        c.push(num);
    } else {

    }
}
System.out.println(c.isEmpty());
return c;
}
```

Here are the tests:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

 import org.junit.Test;

public class StackExampleTest {
private class StackTest extends Stack<Integer> {
    public StackTest(int[] values) {
        for (int i = values.length-1; i > -1; i--) {
            push( values[ i ] );
        }
    }
}
@Test
public void testReflection() {
    Class<?> iClass  = StackExample.class;
    Field[]  iFields = iClass.getDeclaredFields();

    for (Field f : iFields) {
        if (!f.isSynthetic()) {
            fail( "Class shouldn't have any fields [found: \""+f.getName()+"\"]" );
        }
    }
}
@Test
public void testEmpty() {
    int[]          input  = new int[]{ };
    Stack<Integer> stack  = new StackTest( input );
    Stack<Integer> result = StackExample.getEvenNumbers( stack );

    assertTrue( "result should be empty", result.isEmpty() );
    assertTrue( "stack should be empty",  stack .isEmpty() );
    assertTrue( "stack and result cannot be the same object", stack !=    result );
}
@Test
public void test1Odd() {
    int[]          input   = new int[]{ 5 };
    Stack<Integer> stack   = new StackTest( input );
    Stack<Integer> result  = StackExample.getEvenNumbers( stack );

    assertTrue( "result should be empty", result.isEmpty() );

    for (int expected : input) {
        if (stack.isEmpty())
            fail( "\"stack\" empty: '"+ expected +"' expected" );
        else {
            int actual = stack.pop();
            assertEquals( "incorrect result", expected, actual );
        }
    }
    assertTrue( "stack and result cannot be the same object", stack != result );
}
@Test
public void test1Even() {
    int[]          input   = new int[]{ 4 };
    Stack<Integer> stack   = new StackTest( input );
    Stack<Integer> result  = StackExample.getEvenNumbers( stack );

    for (int expected : new int[]{ 4 }) {
        if (result.isEmpty())
            fail( "\"result\" empty: '"+ expected +"' expected" );
        else {
            int actual = result.pop();
            assertEquals( "incorrect result", expected, actual );
        }
    }
    for (int expected : input) {
        if (stack.isEmpty())
            fail( "\"stack\" empty: '"+ expected +"' expected" );
        else {
            int actual = stack.pop();
            assertEquals( "incorrect result", expected, actual );
        }
    }
    assertTrue( "stack and result cannot be the same object", stack != result );
}
@Test
public void testNoneEven() {
    int[]          input   = new int[]{ 9, 77, 3, 5, 11 };
    Stack<Integer> stack   = new StackTest( input );
    Stack<Integer> result  = StackExample.getEvenNumbers( stack );

    assertTrue( "result should be empty", result.isEmpty() );

    for (int expected : input) {
        if (stack.isEmpty())
            fail( "\"stack\" empty: '"+ expected +"' expected" );
        else {
            int actual = stack.pop();
            assertEquals( "incorrect result", expected, actual );
        }
    }
    assertTrue( "stack and result cannot be the same object", stack != result );
}
@Test
public void testSomeEven() {
    int[]          input   = new int[]{ 44, 77, 8, 3, 5, 12 };
    Stack<Integer> stack   = new StackTest( input );
    Stack<Integer> result  = StackExample.getEvenNumbers( stack );

    for (int expected : new int[]{ 44, 8, 12 }) {
        if (result.isEmpty())
            fail( "\"result\" empty: '"+ expected +"' expected" );
        else {
            int actual = result.pop();
            assertEquals( "incorrect result", expected, actual );
        }
    }
    for (int expected : input) {
        if (stack.isEmpty())
            fail( "\"stack\" empty: '"+ expected +"' expected" );
        else {
            int actual = stack.pop();
            assertEquals( "incorrect result", expected, actual );
        }
    }
    assertTrue( "stack and result cannot be the same object", stack != result );
}
@Test
public void testAllEven() {
    int[]          input   = new int[]{ 12, 22, 6, 14, 12 };
    Stack<Integer> stack   = new StackTest( input );
    Stack<Integer> result  = StackExample.getEvenNumbers( stack );

    for (int expected : input) {
        if (result.isEmpty())
            fail( "\"result\" empty: '"+ expected +"' expected" );
        else {
            int actual = result.pop();
            assertEquals( "incorrect result", expected, actual );
        }
    }
    for (int expected : input) {
        if (stack.isEmpty())
            fail( "\"stack\" empty: '"+ expected +"' expected" );
        else {
            int actual = stack.pop();
            assertEquals( "incorrect result", expected, actual );
        }
    }
    assertTrue( "stack and result cannot be the same object", stack !=    result );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will fail `test1Odd` if stack contains an odd number:

```
if(length(stack)==1)
{
    return stack;
}
```

Either give up on this optimization or check if it contains even element.